# Sum of squares of two Ito processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

**Problem**
Given two Ito processes such that
$$A_t = a +  \int_0^t B_u dW_u$$
$$B_t = b -  \int_0^t A_u dW_u$$
We need to show that $a^2e^t + b^2e^t = A_t^2 + B_t^2$

**My attempt**
I use Ito's formula to evalute $d(A_t^2)$
$$d(A_t^2) = 2A_tdA_t + (dA_t)^2$$
Substitute $dA_t = B_udW_u$ and get
$$d(A_t^2) = 2 A_t B_t d W_t + B_t^2 dt$$
Similarly, I get
$$d(B_t^2) = - 2 A_t B_t d W_t + A_t^2 dt$$

In the full form $A_t^2 = \tilde a + 2\int_0^t A_uB_u dW_u + \int_0^t B_u^2 du$

Summing up $A_t^2$ and $ B_t^2$ result in $2 A_t B_t d W_t$ canceling out, so the result it
$$A_t^2 + B_t^2 = \tilde a + \tilde b + \int_0^t(A_u^2 + B_u^2)du$$
The obtained expression does not look like the one we needed to proof. Besides, it's not clear where the exponent comes from

Comment: Good job so far. $\tilde{a}+\tilde{b}$ should be $a^2+b^2$. The last equation can be viewed as and ODE for $f(t)=A^2_t+B^2_t$ which has a simple solution.

Comment: @KurtG. I thought the same, but what about the validity of considering only ODE?

Comment: You showed that $A^2+B^2$ isn't stochastic anymore - even though $A$ and $B$ individually are. Interesting exercise. Nothing wrong with it. Obviously, the different signs in front of the $dW$-integrals are responsible for a cancellation.

Comment: @KurtG. We get that $f(t) = C + \int_0^t f(u)du$? But, it results in something like $f(t) = e^{t}$? Still, does not look like multiplication by exponent...

Comment: The solution to $f(t) = C + \int_0^t f(u)\,du$ is without doubt $f(t)=Ce^t\,.$ To understand what is going on with that system of SDEs observe that the random shocks that $dW$ applies to the vector $(A,B)$ are always orthogonal to $(A,B)$. Therefore the distance to the origin of that vector is not random. It only has a deterministic drift.